# How can use Regular expression for Column Validation in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list, validation, regex

Is there a way that i can use the newly introduced "column validation" in Sharepoint 2010 Lists to validate that the value conforms to a regular expression?

For example: if i create a column for email, I will need to make sure that users enter a valid (from regex point of view) email address. Is there a way to do that using the column validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like regex is not exported in the new column validation feature.

References:
http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/sp2010/Site+Column+Validation

Laura Rogers blogged about a way to pull it off in a Data View Web Part:
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=83